# Как задать имя переменной используя конкатенацию: строковое значение + значение переменной?(Например, имя Ar1 получается как "Ar"+1)

Tags: java

Как задать имя переменной используя конкатенацию: строковое значение + значение переменной?(Например, имя Ar1 получается как "Ar"+1)

Answer (score 1):

Думаю что никак. Возможно для ваших целей подойдет HashMap:

```
  Map<String, String> yourMap = new HashMap<>();
  int i = 1;
  yourMap.put("Ar"+i, "yourValue");
  int x = 2;
  yourMap.put("Ar"+x, "yourValueOther");
```

Потом можете получать ваши необходимые элементы по нужной переменной например:

```
String result = yourMap.get("Ar" + i );
```

Comment: С HashMap никогда не работал, я вставил код, как исправить ошибки:
Cannot infer type arguments for HashMap<>
HashMap cannot be resolved to a type
JMap cannot be resolved to a type
Map cannot be resolved to a type
Syntax error, insert "}" to complete ClassBody
The import sun.jvm cannot be resolved

Comment: Спасибо, я добавил несколько imports. Помощь больше не нужна